# Conditional Format Date From Date In Another Cell

Tags: excel, date, conditional-statements, format, formula

I have three date columns, Manufacture Date (B2), Inspection Date (C2), Future Inspection Date (D2), the Future Inspection Date column looks at columns B2 & C2 to determine the latest date from both, and then adds three years to come up with a Future Inspection Date.

I would like to apply conditional formatting to the Future Inspection Date column (D2) which is based on the most recent date of columns B2 & C2, for example if C2 is the latest date of 01/01/2020 column D2 will be formatted in the following way.

01/01/2020 additional 0 to 24 months white
01/01/2020 additional 24 to 36 months amber
01/01/2020 additional 36 months red

Would this be possible?

I have tried determining formula but just cant get it to work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'additional _x_ to _y_ months'? If D2 is always +3 years, I'm not sure where these numbers are coming from...

Comment: So can the manufacture date be after the Inspection date? If not, then just check the inspection date un less it is blank.

Comment: Column 'D' takes the most recent date between either column B or C, and then adds three years. Example 1 'B' - 09/01/2018 'C'- 15/01/2023 so column 'D' will be dated 15/01/2026, using column C +3years. Example 2 'B' - 09/01/2018 'C' - No Date - 'D' will be dated 09/01/2021 using column 'B' + 3 years.